# For unsuccessful actions, there should not be outputs

Tags: workflow, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I'm trying to test my workflow with HTTP request action... And when I select Status "Failure" - I can't add Output. But when I send a request without testing - I can see Output from the failed action (i.e. Status code, Body, Headers).

So, how can I test this one with Output parameters? Actually, I have to handle Status code in the subsequent actions.

[image: Error]
[image: Proof of work]

My workflow seems like this:

```
{
  "definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "actions": {
      "Bad": {
        "inputs": {
          "body": "Bad: @{outputs('HTTP')['statusCode']}",
          "statusCode": 503
        },
        "kind": "http",
        "runAfter": {
          "HTTP": [
            "TIMEDOUT",
            "FAILED"
          ]
        },
        "type": "Response"
      },
      "HTTP": {
        "inputs": {
          "method": "GET",
          "uri": "@{appsetting('externalServiceUrl')}/api/entities/"
        },
        "runAfter": {},
        "type": "Http"
      },
      "Success": {
        "inputs": {
          "body": "Success",
          "statusCode": 200
        },
        "kind": "http",
        "runAfter": {
          "HTTP": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        },
        "type": "Response"
      }
    },
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "triggers": {
      "manual": {
        "inputs": {},
        "kind": "Http",
        "type": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "kind": "Stateful"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Actually, I have to handle Status code in the subsequent actions.

You just need to change the status as `Succeeded` and in Status Code when you scroll down you can find a bunch of status codes that you can set.

[image]

Additionally, To Handle Status Code further you can also use the `Condition` action of `Control` check if the HTTP connector has satisfied the conditions that we are looking for. Here is my logic app workflow.

[image]

So the Success executes for 200 and 202 status and rest all codes comes under bad action when executed.

Comment: "You just need to change the status as `Succeeded`". It's will not work. Since the `Run after` rule for `Bad` is set for the `Failed` case, this is how it works in a real case.
The second proposed solution makes sense. But I already have a bit more complex workflow and I don't really want to change it for tests :) But, if there is no other way to test - I will...
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My solution in Acceptance tests to test this workflow - I just mocked API using WireMock.
But lack of possibility to test with the default functionality (without Kludge) seems like a bug.